# UNIX paste columns and insert zeros for all missing values

Tags: text-processing, awk, paste

I would like to merge specific columns from two txt files containing varying number of rows, but same number of columns (as shown below):

```
  file1:
  xyz   desc1   12
  uvw   desc2   55
  pqr   desc3   12

  file2:
  xyz   desc1   56
  uvw   desc2   88


  Preferred output:
  xyz   desc1   12  56
  uvw   desc2   55  88
  pqr   desc3   12   0
```

Currently I use the paste command using awk as:

```
  paste <(awk '{print $1}' file1) <(awk '{print $2}' file1) <(awk '{print $3}' file1) <(awk '{print $3}' file2)
```

But this seems to merge only columns that overlap. Is there a way in awk to insert zeros instead of omitting the row itself?

I need to combine 100 files together such that my output file will contain 102 columns.

Comment: Does the order of columns matter? (The solution by @fedorqui always pads the line with zeros at the end, no matter from which file the value(s) came.)

Comment: It would be interesting to get this comment in my answer so I can be aware of :)

Comment: @fedorqui That's why I mentioned you. But the OP must clarify his requirements, so I asked the question here.

Comment: @Dubu note the notification didn't arrive to me, because there wasn't any comment from me in this section.

Comment: @fedorqui Ah, sorry, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If column-order is important, i.e. numbers from the same file should be kept in the same column, you need to add padding while reading the different files. Here is one way that works with GNU awk:

*merge.awk*

```awk
# Set k to be a shorthand for the key
{ k = $1 SUBSEP $2 }

# First element with this key, add zeros to align it with other rows
!(k in h) {
  for(i=1; i<=ARGIND-1; i++)
    h[k] = h[k] OFS 0 
}

# Remember the data element
{ h[k] = h[k] OFS $3 }

# Before moving to the next file, ensure that all rows are aligned
ENDFILE {
  for(k in h) {
    if(split(h[k], a) < ARGIND)
      h[k] = h[k] OFS 0
  }
}

# Print out the collected data
END {
  for(k in h) {
    split(k, a, SUBSEP)
    print a[1], a[2], h[k]
  }
}
```

Here are some test files: `f1`, `f2`, `f3` and `f4`:

```
$ tail -n+1 f[1-4]
==> f1 <==
xyz desc1 21
uvw desc2 22
pqr desc3 23

==> f2 <==
xyz desc1 56
uvw desc2 57

==> f3 <==
xyz desc1 87
uvw desc2 88

==> f4 <==
xyz desc1 11
uvw desc2 12
pqr desc3 13
stw desc1 14
arg desc2 15
```

#### Test 1

```
awk -f merge.awk f[1-4] | column -t
```

Output:

```
pqr  desc3  23  0   0   13
uvw  desc2  22  57  88  12
stw  desc1  0   0   0   14
arg  desc2  0   0   0   15
xyz  desc1  21  56  87  11
```

#### Test 2

```
awk -f merge.awk f2 f3 f4 f1 | column -t
```

Output:

```
pqr  desc3  0   0   13  23
uvw  desc2  57  88  12  22
stw  desc1  0   0   14  0
arg  desc2  0   0   15  0
xyz  desc1  56  87  11  21
```

#### Edit:

If the output should be tab-separated, set the output field separator accordingly:

```
awk -f merge.awk OFS='\t' f[1-4]
```

Comment: Does this result in tab-separated column? If not how to make this as a tab separated column?

Comment: @biobudhan: No this produces space separated columns. I updated the answer to (more correctly) use OFS when generating the table. With this change you can specify the output separator by setting OFS on the command line, either `awk -v OFS='\t' -f merge.awk FILES` or as a post argument `awk -f merge.awk OFS='\t' FILES`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ awk '
    FNR == NR { a[$1,$2] = $3; next }
    {
        print $0,(($1,$2) in a) ? a[$1,$2] : "0"
    }
' file2 file1
xyz   desc1   12 56
uvw   desc2   55 88
pqr   desc3   12 0
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning earlier. I have 100 files like this, how do I do this?

Comment: You compare each two files or compare 100 files?

Comment: compare 100 files

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long, but works:

```
$ cat file1 file2 | awk '{a[$1FS$2]=a[$1FS$2]FS$3; b[$1FS$2]++} END {for (i in b) max=max<b[i]?b[i]:max; for (i in a) {printf "%s %s", i, a[i]; for (j=b[i]; j<max; j++) printf "%s0", FS  printf "%s", RS}}' 
pqr desc3  12 0
xyz desc1  12 56
uvw desc2  55 88
```

The awk block can be formatted as this:

```
awk '{a[$1FS$2]=a[$1FS$2]FS$3; b[$1FS$2]++}
      END {for (i in b) max=max<b[i]?b[i]:max
          for (i in a) {printf "%s%s%s", i, FS, a[i]
                        for (j=b[i]; j<max; j++) printf "%s0", FS
                        printf "%s", RS}
          }'
```

The idea is to print all files and then catch the repeated values in the array `a[$1 $2]`. Also, `b[$1 $2]` contains the amount of times a pair (`$1`, `$2`) appeared.

In the `END{}` block we keep looping through values and completing with as much `0`s as are missing from number of elements to maximum number of elements.

Comment: @biobudhan: Note that this solution does not preserve the columns, e.g. numbers from the `pqr` record will always end up in the first column no matter the order of the file arguments. This may or may not be a problem depending on what the you want.

Comment: Thor: columns should be preserved! :-)